# Custom url scheme as base URL in axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Is this possible to set custom url scheme as baseURL in axios?
What I want to achieve:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({baseURL: 'my-custom-scheme://'})
axiosInstance({methods: 'GET', url: '/some-other/endpoint'})
```

and I want my get call to be done to `my-custom-scheme://some-other/endpoint`.
but what I am getting in `my-custom-scheme:/some-other/endpoint`.

The problem is axios is replacing my `//` with `/` making it impossible to set custom url scheme as baseURL.
Is there any way to achieve the above?

Comment: Axios is an HTTP client.  If you are trying to make it speak something other than HTTP(S), then I doubt is this is doable.

Comment: It would be possible. E.g. `axios.create({baseURL: 'custom-protocol://myendpoint'})` and then using `axios.get('/users')` will call `custom-protocol://myendpoint/users`. 
The problem appears when `baseURL` is just the protocol and ends with `//`